# Filter array of objects but return only specific properties - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

How to filter an array of objects with a condition and return only specific properties of filtered objects?

I know we can use filter followed by map to achieve this. But I am looking for more simple solution.

For ex: 
`let arr = [{name:"lala", id: 1}, {name: "coco", id:2}, {name: "lala", id:3}]`

Suppose if I want only ids of name "lala".

Output should be,

`[{id: 1}, {id: 3}]`

Comment: Filter and map is exactly the right way. If you want to avoid multiple iteration you have to use one loop like foreach.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to combine both mapping and filtering in the same operation. If you want to make it super concise, you can use object destructuring in the second argument of the reduce callback:

```js
let arr = [{name:"lala", id: 1}, {name: "coco", id:2}, {name: "lala", id:3}];

let filteredMappedArr = arr.reduce((acc, { name, id }) => {
  if (name === 'lala')
    acc.push({ id });
    
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filteredMappedArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using `filter` and `map`;

```js
let arr = [{name:"lala", id: 1}, {name: "coco", id:2}, {name: "lala", id:3}]
const result = arr
  .map(({id, name}) => name === 'lala' ? { id }: null) // check if the name is 'lala' then return an object with the id, otherwise return null
  .filter(item => !!item); // Finally filter out the null values
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

The next simplest would be reduce

```js
let arr = [{name:"lala", id: 1}, {name: "coco", id:2}, {name: "lala", id:3}];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((values, value) =>
  {
    if (value.name === 'lala') values.push({ id: value.id });
    return values;
  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` followed by `map` is probably the most readable solution, but if you're looking to do it all in one step, you're looking at the classic `for` loop or using `reduce`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and return either a new obejct or an empty array which has no value for flattening.

```js
let array = [{ name: "lala", id: 1 }, { name: "coco", id: 2 }, { name: "lala", id: 3 }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ id, name }) => name === 'lala' ? [{ id }] : []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Elegant solution but also much slower than other methods given here - in case speed and scalability matters (see https://jsbench.me/l6k8ugcegd)

Answer (score 0):

using [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) functions:

```js
let arr = [{name:"lala", id: 1}, {name: "coco", id:2}, {name: "lala", id:3}]

let newArr = arr.filter((elm) => (elm.name === 'lala')).map( (elm) => {return {id:elm.id}});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [
  { name: "lala", id: 1 },
  { name: "coco", id: 2 },
  { name: "lala", id: 3 },
];
let a = [];
arr.filter(({ name, id }) => {
  if (name === "lala") {
    a.push({ id });
  }
});
console.log(a);
```

with filter we check for the condition where name matches 'lala' if yes then we push id to new array...that's simple

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.